# set breakpoint in Python via the CPython API by line number without changing the passed code

Tags: python, ios, c, objective-c, cpython

I'm developing a Python IDE for iOS, and any IDE has a Debug, so I need to implement it. Reading various sources, I found out that Python has a breakpoint() function, but it needs to be embedded in the code that will be passed for execution, therefore I need to personally download the code from each file and put down the breakpoint. This is not very convenient for me. The only thing I came up with is an infinite (until pressing the IDE "continue" button) while. Is there a more, if I may say, more beautiful solution to this problem?

P.S:

```
static int trace_function(PyObject *obj, PyFrameObject *frame, int event, PyObject *arg) {
// Проверяем событие, если это событие линии
if (event == PyTrace_LINE) {
    // Получаем текущий номер строки
    
    int current_line = PyFrame_GetLineNumber(frame);
    printf("Currently at line: %d\n", current_line);
    
    if (current_line == 2) {
        printf("Breakpoint at line: %d\n", current_line);
        while (1) {
            
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

this function is passed to the Python execution tracking system. For example, the while loop is simply infinite.